# Execute a function within a certain time limit and if it does, send it along with the response

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, python-asyncio

Here is the code,

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

def return_along_with_prediction(self, data):
  # Preprocess the data and returns a dataframe
  df = transform_to_dataframe(data)
  model= Model()
  result = Job().start_job(model)
  return result

class Job:
  def create_job_id(self):
    # Some logic to compute job id
    return job_id

  def start_job(self, model):
    job_id=self.create_job_id()
    prediction = model.predict()
    return {‘id’: job_id, ‘prediction’: prediction}


App = Flask(__name__)

@App.route(‘/get-job-id’, method=[‘POST’])
def myfunc():
  result = return_along_with_prediction(request.json)
  return jsonify(result)
```

In this application, the model.predict() takes a longer time to complete which delays the response.
What I want is to send both job id and the prediction if model.predict() gets completed within 1 min.
Otherwise, send only the job id without the prediction.

Here is what I have tried.

```
import asyncio
from flask import Flask, jsonify

def return_along_with_prediction(self, data):
  # Preprocess and returns a dataframe
  df = transform_to_dataframe(data)
  model= Model()
  result = Job().start_job(model)
  return result

class Job:
  def create_job_id(self):
    # Some logic to compute job id
    return job_id

  async def operation(self, future, model):
    result = await model.predict()
    future.set_result(result)

  def start_job(self ,model):
    job_id=self.__create_job_id(n=6)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    future = asyncio.Future()
    asyncio.ensure_future(self.operation(future,model))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
    return {‘id’: job_id, ‘prediction’: future.result()}


App = Flask(__name__)

@App.route(‘/get-job-id’, method=[‘POST’])
def fun():
  result = predict(request.json)
  return jsonify(result)
```

I thought this could be accomplished by async and await. What am I doing wrong?
I don’t know where to put the 1 min time limit in this code either.

Comment: Rather than trying to send the prediction in the response, you could use celery to send the response async. Maybe via email, slack or S3 upload, just saying.

Comment: you should treat asyncio like an opinionated framework, which defines your program's architecture - same as flask. Not a set of functions which you can call whenever you want. In general, asyncio and flask are quite incompatible